# ¿Cómo insertar variable en mailto usando Google Apps Script en Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Soy novato en programar. Quiero automatizar la entrega de correos 
    como estos programando desde el script de googlesheet.

```
Hola,
Tienes un nuevo mensaje de: Carlos

Contesta desde aquí
```

...donde el "Contesta desde aquí" va con link mailto al correo de Carlos. 
    Este es mi script hecho en google sheet:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
    var user1 = "micorreo@micorreogmail.com";
    var correo = e.values[2]
    var message = "Hola," + "<br>" + "Tienes un nuevo mensaje de: " + e.values[1] + "<br>" + "<br>" 
      + "<a href=mailto:'correo'?Subject=ASUNTO>Contesta desde aquí</a>";

    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: user1,
        subject:"Nuevo mensaje",
        htmlBody: message,
    })
}
```

Lo que quiero es que mailto lea las diferentes direcciones de correo que se irán enlistando en la planilla google a medida que las personas completan el formulario.
Gracias a todo el que me pueda ayudar. 
Saludos.

[image: mailto y google sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes saber es que Google Apps Script está basado en JavaScript.
Luego debes saber de cadenas, concatenación, escapado de caracteres y HTML, particularmente la creación de hipervínculos (enlaces) de tipo `mailto`.

Cambia la siguiente parte de de tu código

```
"<a href=mailto:'correo'?Subject=ASUNTO>Contesta desde aquí</a>"
```

por

```
"<a href=\"mailto:" + correo + "?Subject=ASUNTO\">Contesta desde aquí</a>"
```

Nótese que se han agregado `\"` (comilla doble escapada) y reemplazado `'correo'` por `" + correo + "` ( en JavaScript el signo más se usa para concatenar cadenas de texto ).

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduccion_a_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks

Comment: Gracias Rubén. Eres un genio, bueno yo también soy bruto en esto de programar. 
Hice lo que me dijiste y funcionó todo perfecto. No sabes cuánto he buscado la solución.

MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!!
Saludos de Chile.

Comment: Estimado, un detallito final. La etiqueta body no me está funcionando correctamente. ¿Puedes mirar qué esta mal?:

"<a href=\"mailto:" + correo + "?Subject=ASUNTO" + "?Body=CUERPO\">Contesta desde aquí</a>" 

Agradecido nuevamente.

Comment: @wacoss El problema es que has puesto dos `?`. Por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Si requieres mayor orientación publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Todo conforme muchas gracias nuevamente. ¿Sabes si es posible poner una variable dentro de la etiqueta body?

"<a href=\"mailto:" + correo + "?Subject=Asunto&Body=CuerpoMensaje + VariableNuevaAqui\">Contesta desde aquí</a>" 

Lo intenté pero no me funcionó.
Saludos!

Comment: Sí es posible. Te sugiero publicar una nueva pregunta.

Comment: pregunta hecha aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318810/insertar-variable-en-etiqueta-body-usando-mailto 

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
    var user1 = "micorreo@micorreogmail.com";
    var correo = e.values[2]
    var message = "Hola," + "<br>" + "Tienes un nuevo mensaje de: " + e.values[1] + "<br>" + "<br>" 
      + "<a href=\"mailto:"+correo+"?Subject=ASUNTO"+"&Body=Estimado: " +variableopcional+"\">Contesta desde aquí</a>";

    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: user1,
        subject:"Nuevo mensaje",
        htmlBody: message,
    })
}
```